# Litecoin mining wifi bandwidth requirements

Tags: litecoin

Next week i will be mining with a total of 13Mh/s with my rigs.

What wifi bandwidth do i need to install? I've no idea how much wi-fi bandwidth is needed. I was thinking of using a 3G USB of 1GB limit/month if it is not required much bandwidth. Is it enough?

Regards,